# What is the most practical way to open a File Explorer to the current directory in a File Explorer?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Currently I'm doing the following to open a file explorer **to the same directory**:

- Click the address bar & copy the address
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> & paste the address to the address bar

Is there a shorter way to do this, possibly with shortcuts?

Comment: enable navigation pane, right click on folder, select open in new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a new window in the same folder you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>